# db2 looping through all tables listed in the sysibm.syscolumns output for specific column and specific column value

Tags: db2

In DB2 I ran a query:

select * from sysibm.syscolumns a where a.tbcreator='ABCD' AND a.name='EMP_ID'

The output shows all the tables containing specific column name EMP_ID in the entire schema.

Now, I need to scan/loop through the resulting output table above and check for **specific** EMP_ID **value** in all table names listed under the column Tbname (in the output above).

In other words, pull out all the tables in the schema, which may possibly contain column EMP_ID equal to '1234'.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this kind of task using a compound statement in Db2.

What follows is a minimal example in a single transaction.

You need to set your statement terminator to `@` to run it

```
CREATE TABLE FIND_VALUE (
    TABSCHEMA  VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
,   TABNAME    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
,   ROW_COUNT  BIGINT       NOT NULL
)
@
BEGIN
    FOR C AS 
        SELECT 'INSERT INTO FIND_VALUE'
            || ' SELECT ''' || TABSCHEMA || ''',''' || TABNAME || ''''
            || ', COUNT(*)' 
            || ' FROM "' ||  TABSCHEMA || '"."' || TABNAME || '"' 
            || ' WHERE "' || COLNAME || '" = 1234' AS S
        FROM 
             SYSCAT.COLUMNS
        JOIN SYSCAT.TABLES  USING ( TABSCHEMA, TABNAME ) 
        WHERE
             TYPE = 'T'
        AND  COLNAME = 'EMP_ID' 
    DO       
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE C.S;
    END FOR;
END
@
SELECT * FROM FIND_VALUE
```